# about air(flex) application server connection

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mxml

The application which developed by AIR(flex builder),Could connect with server(php) side.

Comment: Can you post some code or actual error messages? Anything?

Comment: Actually i need the help how can i do this. Give some tutorials is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. You could use AMFPHP or ZendAMF for instance. Here are some good articles and tutorials on how to accomplish such thing http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html.